# Free Download Manager Development [FDM]

Tags: software-development

Is the development of Free Download Manager halted? The last code committed was in 2014 :/

[Here is a link to the repository.](http://sourceforge.net/p/freedownload/code/HEAD/tree/)

[image: Sourceforge screenshot.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the state of a specific open-source project, and not (per se) about open source itself. See http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/356/are-questions-about-specific-open-source-projects-on-topic

Comment: @kdopen I understand. But next time where should I ask this type of questions? StackExchange is kind of the one stop station for all these type of techy questions. Plus, FDM's own forum is inactive for a long type. For future what should be my best course of action?

Comment: I'm not really sure where to suggest. SE has seemingly hundreds of sites, but none of them are *meant* to be used as product-support. That said, some FOSS projects do direct people to StackOverflow for support questions. This site, however, has decided these questions are definitely off-topic

Comment: @kdopen The issue there is that people redirect those to Stack Overflow for their *on-topic programming-related* questions. Statuses of projects probably won't fit there. In a sense, I feel like we should reconsider this. Maybe we can talk in chat?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I don't think there's any merit to this kind of question - you can't be an expert at this, you can search harder.

Comment: It kind of feels weird seeing a down vote on this question: there's nothing inherently wrong with this question, and this is the kind of question I'd probably expect to see on an open source site. If it's off-topic, close vote, discuss in meta or in chat. P.S. @curiousdannii What do you mean there's no merit to that kind of question?

Comment: @Ziz There's no real merit because the only way to answer this is to ask the maintainers directly - which would take as much time as it would to ask here. Downvotes are warranted for lack of interest and research. If it's ontopic okay, if not okay.

Comment: My reason for asking it here was that though I tried to contact the support of FDM website, there was no response. Theie forum has no active post may be for the last one year. Then I thought may be I could ask in SE, somebody there may know what's up. I do not know any other site where open source enthusiasts gather together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Editorial: I voted-to-close this question in line with the community's decision that this type of question was off-topic. That does not mean, however, that it may not be time to reconsider that position.)

A little searching found the following announcement from December 24th, 2015

http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/board/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17363

This forum post states that:

> We're proud to announce that the new Free Download Manager 5.1 is now available to public. After months of hard work and extensive testing, our team would like to offer you a more streamlined UI with a friendlier approach to configuration. Thanks to the revamped software engine, you will enjoy  efficient and stable multi-thread downloading as well as overall better performance and responsiveness. FDM5 features cross-platform support for both Windows and Mac OS. You're very welcome to try out the configuration capabilities FDM5 comes with and offer new ideas and options on our forum!

So it would appear that FDM is still alive and being actively worked on.

Interestingly, however, the only link to source code I can find on that site brings me back to the sourceforge page you cited. I also see mention of "FDM lite" which suggests they may be planning to switch to a paid-software model for new releases.

However, according to the license file at http://svn.code.sf.net/p/freedownload/code/trunc/license.txt it was (originally at least) GPLv3.

I was able to checkout some source code with

```
svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/freedownload/code
```

But the log shows

```
$ svn log -l 3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r52 | alervd | 2014-05-16 02:29:56 -0700 (Fri, 16 May 2014) | 1 line

+ GeckoSDK v30.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r51 | alervd | 2014-05-16 02:06:25 -0700 (Fri, 16 May 2014) | 1 line

missing files from previous commit.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r50 | alervd | 2014-05-15 12:56:06 -0700 (Thu, 15 May 2014) | 6 lines

FDM ver. 3.9.4 build 1473
New features:
[+] Brand new Google Chrome extension.
[+] Bittorrent: UPnP, NAT-PMP, Local Peer Discovery.
[+] Firefox 30 support.
[–] General bug fixes.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Given that they jumped from V3.9.4 to V5.0, and the Beta announcement talks of a 'revamped software engine' - they may have completely rewritten it to avoid the GPLv3 requirement to open source the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes projects move around, SourceForge got a bit of bad reputation lately (and places like [github](http://github.com) have nicer interfaces/offer support for distributed workflow, not just "store my project"). The work might continue under another name somewhere else too.

You should try contacting the addresses given for contributors.

What is your interest? You could just pick up development (even elsewhere), if you don't find some continuation.

If you want to use it, I'd suggest searching for better supported alternatives. If it was abandoned, it must have been for a reason. At very least little user interest, at worst unsalvageable design or other problems. Little user interest means little real testing, thus the possibility for many bugs, even severe ones, including grievous security problems.

Comment: I have contacted the support of that website, but no luck so far. You have mentioned some interesting points (Y